# Unable to add key to Azure key-vault backed Databricks scope

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, scopes

I am trying to create a keyvault backed scope in databricks. I am able to successfully create the scope but when I try to add a key to the scope I see the following error:

```
Error: b'{"error_code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Cannot write secrets to Azure KeyVault-backed scope abc"}'
```

These are steps I have followed and all commands were run on windows cmd:

1. Create key vault in Azure
2. Generate AAD token for databricks - `az account get-access-token --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`
3. Add AAD token to environment variables on windows
4. Add AAD token to databricks cfg file on windows - `databricks configure --aad-token`
5. Create scope - `databricks secrets create-scope --scope abc --scope-backend-type AZURE_KEYVAULT --resource-id <keyvault-id> --dns-name <keyvault-dns> --initial-manage-principal users`
6. Add key to scope - `databricks secrets put --scope abc --key abc-key` **<< this where I see the error**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#azure-key-vault-backed-scopes) this is not possible:

> To reference secrets stored in an [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview), you can create a secret scope backed by Azure Key Vault. You can then leverage all of the secrets in the corresponding Key Vault instance from that secret scope. Because the Azure Key Vault-backed secret scope is a read-only interface to the Key Vault, the `PutSecret` and `DeleteSecret` [Secrets API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets) operations are not allowed. To manage secrets in Azure Key Vault, you must use the Azure [SetSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/set-secret/set-secret) REST API or Azure portal UI.

Using Az CLI, you could use the `az keyvault secret set` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set).